# Unterschied: »fürs Erste«, »vorerst«, »erst einmal«?

Tags: meaning, difference

Es wäre gut die Feinheiten und Unterschiede in der Bedeutung und Benutzung zu kennen.

Comment: Ich bin auch gespannt. Nicht alle funktionieren immer aber keine Ahnung warum. "Das reicht fürs Erste/vorerst/erstmal" geht. Aber "Ich mache erstmal A dann B" ist richtig und "Ich mache vorerst A dann B" ist falsch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ich habe schon gestern versucht eine Antwort zu formulieren, aber beim Schreiben habe ich bemerkt, dass jeder Versuch irgend ein Kriterium als Unterschied zu benennen darin endet, dass sich dieses Kriterium als nicht haltbar erweist.

Ich gebe hier einmal wieder, was meine Recherchen ergeben haben (Alle Zitate aus Wiktionary, Beispiele gekürzt):

---

### [fürs Erste](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/f%C3%BCrs_Erste)

> **Bedeutungen:**
> Zeit: erst einmal; eine Aussage wird mit dieser Redewendung so eingeschränkt, dass sie später noch einmal überarbeitet werden könnte. Es wird also keine endgültige Lösung vorgestellt.
> **Synonyme:**
> vorläufig, zunächst
> **Beispiele:**
>
> - Ich gedenke fürs Erste nicht, Ihrer Forderung nachzukommen.
> - Mit der Erstellung dieses Reports ist damit für mich fürs Erste der Agenda-Punkt 3.1 erledigt.
> - Mir reichts für Erste, ich gehe Duschen.
> - Gut, dass der neue Chef diesen Irrsinn wenigstens fürs Erste beendet hat.

---

### [vorerst](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/vorerst)

> **Bedeutungen:**
> fürs Erste, erst einmal, unter dem Vorbehalt, dass es sich ändern wird
> **Beispiele:**
>
> - Zu den Gerüchten um Entlassungen möchte der Chef vorerst keine Stellung nehmen.
> - Vorerst werde die Verbindung eingleisig geführt, bis zum Wochenende folge das zweite Streckengleis.

---

### [erstmal](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/erstmal)

(Wiktionary hat keinen Eintrag über *»erst einmal«*)

> **Bedeutungen:**
> umgangssprachlich: bevor etwas anderes geschieht
> **Beispiele:**
>
> - Ich mache jetzt erstmal Frühstück, dann schreibe ich den Bericht zu Ende.
> - Erstmal gehst du dich waschen, dann kommst Du zum Abendessen.
> - Erstmal werden keine Mitarbeiter entlassen.
> - Um das Schlangengehege reinigen zu können, muss die Reptilienfachfrau erstmal alle Giftschlangen einfangen.
> - Hat man erstmal verstanden, wie der Mechanismus funktioniert, kann man ganz eigene Pop-up-Bücher basteln.
> - Die 21-jährige Londonerin war erstmal baff, als sie sich auf DER Hypeliste schlechthin wiederfand - dem "Sound Of 2016" der BBC.
> - IWF-Chefin Lagarde kann aufatmen – erstmal

---

### Fazit

Die Begriffe *»fürs Erste«* und *»vorerst«* scheinen mir fast deckungsgleiche Synonyme zu sein. Es gibt vielleicht äußerst subtile Nuancen in der mitschwingenden Stimmung, die lassen sich aber kaum in Worte fassen.

Die Begriffe *»erstmal«* und *»erst einmal«* haben zwar eine sehr ähnliche Bedeutung aber eben doch nicht ganz gleich. Während es bei *»fürs Erste«* und *»vorerst«* darum geht, dass die beschriebene Situation ein Provisorium ist, das einer späteren Überarbeitung bedarf, möchte man mit *»erstmal«* und *»erst einmal«* ausdrücken, dass die beschriebene Situation der erste Schritt in einer Sequenz mehrerer Schritte ist. Dieser erste Schritt ist bereits so, wie er gemacht wurde, in Ordnung. Er muss nicht nachbessert werden. Aber sein voller Nutzen kann sich erst entfalten, wenn auch die anderen Schritte dieser Sequenz ausgeführt werden.

Ich gebe aber zu, dass die im letzten Absatz geäußerte Unterscheidung nicht auf alle Beispiele zu 100% anwendbar ist. Es gibt keine strikte Differenzierung, sondern nur Tendenzen.